# Howto access the passed variable in a custom directive with JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have made a custom directive and can access the passed variable in the direct.template within double squiqqly brackets like this `directive.template = '<input/>{{text.incorrectAnswers}}'` but how do I access it in JavaScript so I can change it and then pass it back into my directive.template?

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>    
    <body ng-controller="mainController" style="padding: 20px 0">

        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Company Info</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ng-repeat="text in texts">
                        <div data-show-phrase data-text="text"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
                            var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

                            mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.texts = [
                                    {
                                        body: 'Customer 1 is from [@@blank] and Customer 2 is from [@@blank].',
                                        correctAnswers: 'Berlin;Hamburg',
                                        incorrectAnswers: 'Stuttgart;Munich;Frankfurt'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        body: 'Company 3 is located in [@@blank].',
                                        answers: 'Bremen',
                                        incorrectAnswers: 'Hannover;Dresden;Stuttgart'
                                    }
                                ];
                            });

                            mainApp.directive('showPhrase', function () {
                                var directive = {};
                                directive.restrict = 'A';
                                directive.scope = {
                                    text: '=text'
                                };
                                //var parts = incorrectAnswers.split(';'); //Error: incorrectAnswers is not defined
                                //var parts = $scope.incorrectAnswers.split(';'); //Error: incorrectAnswers is not defined
                                var parts = directive.incorrectAnswers.split(';'); //Error: incorrectAnswers is not defined
                                directive.template = '<input/>{{text.body}}';
                                return directive;
                            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get `scope.text.body=something` ? If i understand ur problem'

Comment: right, that what I want to do but `scope.incorrectAnswers` tells me "scope is not defined" and `directive.scope.incorrectAnswers` is undefined. I just need to know how to access the scope from JavaScript inside the directive.

Comment: You can only access it inside the directive controller/link functions.Eg in the link function, `directive.link = function(scope, elm, attr){ var parts = scope.text.incorrectAnswers.split(';') }`

Comment: Can you try accessing it in `directive.link(scope, element, attrs)` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2-way bound properties available as a part of the scope object and that cannot be accessed during the creation of a directive, because no scope exists yet. You need to at least wait till linking phase or in the controller to access the scope and its properties. If you are using controllerAs syntax (with 1.3.x) then you would turn on `bindToController:true`  to be able to access it as properties of the controller instance. And as long as you use bindings in your template, angular will take care of updating the template for dynamic changes in the bound properties.

Example:-

```
mainApp.directive('showPhrase', function() {
  var directive = {};

  directive.restrict = 'A';

  directive.scope = {
    text: '='
  };
  /*Linking function*/
  directive.link = function(scope, elm) {
    scope.parts = scope.text.incorrectAnswers.split(';');
    console.log(parts)
  }


  directive.template = '<div><input/>{{text.body}} <ul><li ng-repeat="part in parts">{{part}}</li></ul></div>';
  return directive;
});
```

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
mainApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.texts = [{
    body: 'Customer 1 is from [@@blank] and Customer 2 is from [@@blank].',
    correctAnswers: 'Berlin;Hamburg',
    incorrectAnswers: 'Stuttgart;Munich;Frankfurt'
  }, {
    body: 'Company 3 is located in [@@blank].',
    answers: 'Bremen',
    incorrectAnswers: 'Hannover;Dresden;Stuttgart'
  }];
});

mainApp.directive('showPhrase', function() {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'A';
  directive.scope = {
    text: '='
  };
  directive.link = function(scope, elm) {
    scope.parts = scope.text.incorrectAnswers.split(';');
    console.log(parts)
  }


  directive.template = '<div><input/>{{text.body}} <ul><li ng-repeat="part in parts">{{part}}</li></ul></div>';
  return directive;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="mainApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController" style="padding: 20px 0">

  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Company Info</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-repeat="text in texts">
          <div data-show-phrase data-text="text"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```